# Seq of Real Numbers / limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \dots +\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ is equal to

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $2$
4. $\log 2$.

I transformed the given limit to

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{n}{n+1} + \dots +\frac{n}{2n}\right)$ and applied Cauchy's first limit theorem and got the limit $1/2$...

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{n}{n+1} + \dots +\frac{n}{2n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1n} + \frac{1}{1+\frac2n} + \dots +\frac{1}{1+\frac n n}\right)\\=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac kn}$$

is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} dx$.

Comment: Nice one......Thank You....N.S.

Answer (score 0):

Using the harmonic series:$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = H_{2n}-H_n$$
and since $H_{2n} = \ln(2n) + \gamma + o(1) = \ln 2 + \ln n + \gamma + o(1)$ and $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + o(1)$, you get your limit.

Answer (score 0):

the sum is $\ge 1/2$ and $\le $\frac{n}{n+1}$. The last fraction has limit 1.
Therefore if the limit of the sum exists it is between 1/2 and 1.